# Failure preparing: bad parameter or other API misuse in SQLite swift while inserting data

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

```
let db = Database.openDatabase()

let insertStatementString = "INSERT INTO SignupDetails VALUES (\((self.txtUsername.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))), \((self.txtPassword.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))))"

Database.insertIntoSignupDetails(db: db, insertStatementString: insertStatementString)

sqlite3_close(db)
```

The above code contains my query for insert data into the database using SQLite.

I have created a table as shown as below:-

```
let db = Database.openDatabase()
let createTableString =
    """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SignupDetails(
        username CHAR(255),
        password CHAR(255));
        """

Database.createTable(db: (db != nil) ? db : OpaquePointer(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Constant.db) as! String), createTableString: createTableString)

sqlite3_close(db)
```

and I have also successfully executed the following code for table creation:-

```
static func createTable(db: OpaquePointer?, createTableString: String) {    
    var createTableStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil

    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, createTableString, -1, &createTableStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        if sqlite3_step(createTableStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
            print("table created.")
        } else {
            print("table could not be created.")
        }
    } else {
        print("CREATE TABLE statement could not be prepared.")
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(createTableStatement)
}
```

But my problem is when I am trying to insert data into that existing table
getting the error shown as below :-

Code:-

```
    var insertStatement: OpaquePointer?


    guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStatementString, -1, &insertStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
        print("failure preparing: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    if sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_OK {
        print("Successfully inserted row.")
    } else {
        print("Could not insert row.")
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement)
```

Error:-

failure preparing: bad parameter or other API misuse

Comment: If you can't wait to have answers from other people, you could try to share the project link for me (since it's just a demo project based on the screenshot), and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Post code as text and not images please. Also include a print of the insert statement used

Comment: And what does the `insertStatementString` variable contain when you call `insertIntoSignupDetails`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i have included insert statement at the top and from where calling the method included at the bottom.

Comment: Not the code, the value of the variable. What does the string contain, the result of `print(insertStatementString )`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson insertStatementString variable contain the insert query where i am giving the value after collection from the textfield

Comment: Thank you but I am not stupid so I get that from reading the code. Read my previous comment again.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson    INSERT INTO SignupDetails VALUES (gopabandhu@bt.com, 123)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the single quotes around your string variables, the string should be something like

> INSERT INTO SignupDetails VALUES ('gopabandhu@bt.com', '123')

```
let insertStatementString = "INSERT INTO SignupDetails VALUES ('\((self.txtUsername.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)))', '\((self.txtPassword.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)))')"
```

An alternative is to use placeholders in your statement

```
let statement = "INSERT INTO SignupDetails(username, password) VALUES (?, ?)"

if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStatementString, -1, &insertStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
    sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 1, username.utf8String, -1, nil)
    sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 2, password.utf8String, -1, nil)

    if sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_OK {
        //...
    }
}
```

where `username` and `password` are parameters sent to `insertIntoSignupDetails`

Comment: Thank you for your help but still not working getting the same error

Comment: @gdGopabandhu and what does `insertStatementString` look like now

Comment: INSERT INTO SignupDetails VALUES ('gopabandhu@bt.com', '123')
it's throwing while preparing the statement and it has not executed the insertion statement yet

Comment: Please do not build SQL strings containing user-supplied data. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @Corion, Thanks, I was just going to suggest another solution even though I am not sure if this is the problem.

Comment: @Corion i removed user supplied data from SQL insertion statement but no improvement